# Objective C Thread Error

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

How do I handle these errors with no crash report? I believe that the issue that I have discovered is calling a class where a certain thread is suppose to manage of clearing and appending its own buffer..

Here is the report that I have received. I found this report in the console but there were no crash logs found in the device logs (even when the app did crash)

```
Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 4 name:  WebThread

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 4:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fcdeb4 0x32fcd000 + 3764

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fce048 0x32fcd000 + 4168

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                 0x3b2bd040 0x3b226000 + 618560

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                 0x3b2bbd9e 0x3b226000 + 613790

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                 0x3b22eeb8 0x3b226000 + 36536

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                 0x3b22ed44 0x3b226000 + 36164

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 6   WebCore                        0x36f0da40 0x36f03000 + 43584

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f30e 0x3633e000 + 70414

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f1d4 0x3633e000 + 70100

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 5:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fcdeb4 0x32fcd000 + 3764

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fce048 0x32fcd000 + 4168

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                 0x3b2bd040 0x3b226000 + 618560

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                 0x3b2bbd9e 0x3b226000 + 613790

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                 0x3b22eeb8 0x3b226000 + 36536

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                 0x3b22ed44 0x3b226000 + 36164

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 6   Foundation                     0x3603f78a 0x3603b000 + 18314

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 7   Foundation                     0x360e3058 0x3603b000 + 688216

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 8   iOSMad                         0x000ff2e6 0xf5000 + 41702

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 9   Foundation                     0x360ec678 0x3603b000 + 726648

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 10  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f30e 0x3633e000 + 70414

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 11  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f1d4 0x3633e000 + 70100

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 6:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fcdeb4 0x32fcd000 + 3764

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fce048 0x32fcd000 + 4168

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                 0x3b2bd040 0x3b226000 + 618560

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                 0x3b2bbd9e 0x3b226000 + 613790

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                 0x3b22eeb8 0x3b226000 + 36536

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                 0x3b22ed44 0x3b226000 + 36164

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 6   Foundation                     0x36068bc8 0x3603b000 + 187336

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 7   Foundation                     0x360ec678 0x3603b000 + 726648

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f30e 0x3633e000 + 70414

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 9   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f1d4 0x3633e000 + 70100

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 7:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fded98 0x32fcd000 + 73112

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36344cf6 0x3633e000 + 27894

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36344a12 0x3633e000 + 27154

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x363448a0 0x3633e000 + 26784

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 8:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fded98 0x32fcd000 + 73112

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36344cf6 0x3633e000 + 27894

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36344a12 0x3633e000 + 27154

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x363448a0 0x3633e000 + 26784

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 9:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fde594 0x32fcd000 + 71060

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   CoreFoundation                 0x3b2c11f2 0x3b226000 + 635378

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f30e 0x3633e000 + 70414

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f1d4 0x3633e000 + 70100

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 10:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fded98 0x32fcd000 + 73112

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36344cf6 0x3633e000 + 27894

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36344a12 0x3633e000 + 27154

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x363448a0 0x3633e000 + 26784

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 11:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fde594 0x32fcd000 + 71060

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   ExternalAccessory              0x3440f742 0x34409000 + 26434

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   Foundation                     0x360ec678 0x3603b000 + 726648

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f30e 0x3633e000 + 70414

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 4   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f1d4 0x3633e000 + 70100

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 12:

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fde08c 0x32fcd000 + 69772

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36347d2a 0x3633e000 + 40234

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36351f14 0x3633e000 + 81684

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 3   Foundation                     0x36068cca 0x3603b000 + 187594

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 4   ExternalAccessory              0x3440e986 0x34409000 + 22918

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 5   Foundation                     0x360ec678 0x3603b000 + 726648

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 6   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f30e 0x3633e000 + 70414

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3634f1d4 0x3633e000 + 70100

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:  

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>: Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:     r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3c2c0534

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:     r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3c2c0b88      r6: 0x1e57cd14      r7: 0x2fd0ba14

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:     r8: 0x1e57ccf0    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x1f82b498

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:     ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd0ba08      lr: 0x3636d123      pc: 0x32fde350

Feb 18 18:15:58  ReportCrash[14342] <Error>:   cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...
thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a partial dump at best -- where are the rest of the threads?

Comment: Please see the update.. I can't see what is thread 0. I don't understand how I can check.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help in your particular case, but it is often helpful to add "All Exceptions" to your breakpoints in the debugger.  This is done by selecting the Breakpoint Navigator, clicking the + icon in the lower left of the pane and clicking "Add Exception Breakpoint".

Apologies if you've already done this but maybe it will be useful to a future reader.